# Outdoor housing big enough for DSLR?

Tags: outdoor

Can anybody recommend an outdoor camera housing big enough to hold a DSLR (or something like a Canon G1X)?

All the standard CCTV housings I can find have at most about 4" of width inside - I need at least 5".

Doesn't need to be fancy - just something to keep out the snow and rain.

(reasonably priced would be nice)

Comment: I would recommend to build one on your own with some wooden planks and acrylic glass. Make a simple box and cover it with some roofing felt. Easy, cheap and you will get your desired sice.

Comment: @Arjihad your comment is the seed of a good answer. I'd argue that many unnoticed and non-popularized weatherproofing solutions are DIY efforts. Please post your comment as answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

I ordered one of [these from "Camtraptions"](https://store.camtraptions.com/products/new-camera-housing?variant=27865044942931) in the UK:

[image: Image of outdoor camera housing from Camtraptions]

Price was 200 GBP (*$280 USD, including 40 GBP shipping to the US*).

That strikes me as very expensive for a hobby project (*I'm going to put a camera that cost less than that in it*), but it's the only one I have been able to find for less than $1000+ sold by "security" firms.

I know I could make my own (*most online instructions seem to be based on Pelican cases*) but I want to save time and buy one pre-made.

I'm surprised - it's easy to find aluminum "security camera" housings (*at for example Amazon or B&H*) for less than $40. But they're not wide enough for a DSLR.

Sounds like a market opportunity for somebody.

Comment: *Welcome to Photography,  **NOT**  an inexpensive hobby*.

Comment: _Sounds like a market opportunity for somebody._ Perhaps, but considering even DLSR manufacturers don't think the DSLRs themselves aren't a market opportunity (DSLR sales are on the decline, and Canon, Nikon, and Sony have no new DLSR lenses in the product pipeline), I think the market opportunity is gone.

Comment: @scottbb I'm sure smartphone cameras have killed most of the market for higher-end cameras, but I doubt they're being widely used for timelapse and camera trap projects much, so I don't think the market is any smaller than it was for such housings. (FWIW, I'm not using a DSLR either - I'm using a Canon G1X; no slappy mirror to wear out.)

Comment: Also, thanks to whoever edited my answer just to italicize all my parentheticals. I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Look at underwater housings. There are a variety of housings in the USD 200 to 2000 price range.

I like Arjihad's suggestion of a DIY housing. An ammo can (box) and AR (anti-reflective) coated window would cost under USD 50. Edmund Optics carries coated *float glass* for hobbyists, or, use a coated UV filter for the optical port.

Comment: the only problem with underwater housings is that they are almost all fairly form-fitting. That is, there's no room in the housing for extra batteries for longer-term operation, or space for modules for wi-fi (like CamRanger, etc.). OP doesn't specify the time requirements, but it's something to note about underwater housings (which otherwise is a **great** suggestion).